# Continue execution even if hostname is wrong for db in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

My webpage has three sections, top, middle and bottom. and all three section connect to different DB. But given the scenarion if one of the database hostname is messed so the entire page broke and throw error. Is it possible that if somethiing happen to one of the database then that section should not appear but rest of the section show run smoothly?

my database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '1.1.1.1',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'DB',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => 'pre_',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

All three DB is having the same setting except hostname and username. First hostname is 1.1.1.1. second host name 1.1.1.2 and third one is 1.1.1.3 and because of something has happened and it couldn't connect to 1.1.1.2 and gave me error message.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But it's impossible to provide further advice as you haven't shared how that whole system works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create 3 groups of database like:

```
$db['default'] = array(
'hostname' => '1.1.1.1',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'DB',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => 'pre_',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['db2'] = array(
'hostname' => '1.1.1.2',
'username' => 'username2',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'DB',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => 'pre_',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['db3'] = array(
'hostname' => '1.1.1.3',
'username' => 'username3',
'password' => 'password',
'database' => 'DB',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => 'pre_',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

And connect each database:

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);
$DB3 = $this->load->database('db3', TRUE);
```

So you can use each for your needs:

```
$DB1->query();
$DB1->result();
```

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable loading the database helper. For that to work you have to make sure that the database isn't used yet. An alternative would be to create a new database driver which ignores all database changes and always returns null when selecting data. More information on writing a database driver can be found in the docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html